# Store Session ShoppingCart in db

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent, shopping-cart

I'm currently developing a laravel app and want to implement [Laravel Shopping Cart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) in it. But before I do so, I have one question: As I figured out, all shopping card information is stored in the session. If I know log out/close browser/etc., my session is gone, so is the shopping cart.

How can I store shopping cart information in db and restore it, when needed? And: when do i save it in db? and when do I get it out again?

Comment: thats very broad, better to just find a different shopping cart script

Comment: what would be different in other shopping cart scripts? there are like 5 or more for laravel, but what makes others better?

Comment: only 5? well you want one that uses a db, instead of, or as  well as sessions - that would make it better for you.

Comment: Would it make sense to make it all over db and don't work with sessions at all?

Comment: there are pros and cons to every method.

Comment: what would those be? pros: saved permanently even if something crashs, user loggs out, closes the browser, propably more save (session hijacking, etc.?), cons: slower then working with sessions?

Answer (score 1):

File based session or database based session both will destroy on logout,close browser etc.

You need to create 2 tables in your database

table_shopping_cart => id, session_id, user_id, created_at, updated_at, invoice_id etc

table_shopping_cart_items => id, cart_id, item_name, item_qty, price etc

And you can run scheduler or cron query with specific date/time to delete expire entries from both table.

Answer (score -2):

I would say storing the information is a database is a little bit of overkill if it is not a business rule. People often save carts during a shopping spree online and adding the complexity of a data layer at this point sounds like its a little out of scope for this question.

If you were to save it, the cart would need to be associated with a particular login. If that infrastructure already exists then saving their information in a database will be easier.

What type of database are you using?

Comment: I'm using a mysql db, accessing everything with eloquent

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you will need to design a database table(s) that will allow you to store product ID's associated with the user.